# How to get /etc/hosts entries in puppet?

Tags: puppet, hosts, hosts-file

The types `host` and `augeas` can only *set* certain values in `/etc/hosts`. `facter` does not support hosts query.

Now I'm considering

1)writing a ruby function, using `Resolv` library

2)writing a ruby function, and actually read `/etc/hosts` file

Any better ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to get these entries?

Comment: @ℝaphink Long story. In our environment we configured interface bindings. Sometimes one interface has multiple ip addresses, but we cannot get all those addresses via `facter` because `facter` uses `ifconfig` as the underlying command. So we must find a workaround and we consider using hosts entries because they're preconfigured before puppet deployment. Then comes the question.

Comment: Do you manage those entries using Puppet?

Comment: @ℝaphink Currently, no. But maybe in the future. Concerns?

Comment: No. Just thinking that if you did, it would make things easier ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the master to know and work with the contents of the agent's hosts file, you will have indeed no choice but to write a custom fact to do so. Facter `2.x` will be required to retrieve an array/hash structure. The Resolv library would be a very odd choice. You would be better off parsing the file yourself.

Technically, Puppet comes with code to parse the hosts file, but harnessing that would likely be much harder than rolling your own.